# How to read a sql table in Python with declare, drop and multiple selects

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I'm importing a sql-server table into a Python dataframe. But I get an "NoneType" Error.

I believe this error has occured since my sql-code consists of declare, drop and two select statements. I've tried to find some articles about it, but I cannot find the solution.

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(
    "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
    "Server=BI-SQL-TST\DWH_TST;"
    "Database=DWHC_INTER;"
    "Trusted_Connection=yes;" )

sql = """
declare @CostLineStructure nvarchar(100) = 'OWSPL'

drop table if exists #ls;

select *
into #ls
from dSRFinancialStructure
where FinancialStructureID=@CostLineStructure
;

SELECT
  ca.TransactionMonthDate
  , min(ls.DisplayName) as PositionName
  , min(ls.Level) as PositionLevel
  , sum(ca.Amount) as Amount
FROM aSRCostAcc ca
  inner join #ls ls
  on ls.ObjectKey=ca.LedgerAccountKey
  and ls.IsLeaf=0
WHERE ca.MandatorKey='NLA'
  and ca.IsBudget=0
  and ca.TransactionMonthDate  = '2019-06-01'
  and ca.TypeKey<>'5_AX_EXPENSES'
group by
  ca.TransactionMonthDate,
  ls.FinancialStructureKey
order by
  ca.TransactionMonthDate,
  min(ls.FinancialStructure_SortString)
;
"""

df = pd.read_sql(sql, connection)
```

This is the error I've got: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

I would like a working code.

Could somebody give me any tips?

Comment: did you try any sql statements like SELECT 'Hi' FROM aSCostACC ?? just to check connections are working fine?

Comment: Hi Umair, I've tried an easier sql query, and the connection was working well. It's just  this one that I've got an error from.